# Await is not waiting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using node js with mongodb. I'm trying to insert an element in the Collection "users" created previously. Afterwards, I delete the Collection and insert two new "users" and print them.

However, the code isn't being executed in the order I was expecting.

I've tried a few different things. For example, removing dropCollection makes it execute in the desired order but I need to use this function for my code. I also tried not using await and obviously, the same result appears.

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true}, async function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");

  var myobj = { email: "example@example.net", name: "example"};
  await dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 user inserted");
  });

  await dbo.dropCollection("users", function(err, delOK) {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (delOK) console.log("Collection deleted");
  });

  var myobj = { email: "example@example.net", name: "example"};
  await dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 user inserted");
  });

  var myobj = { email: "example2@example.net", name: "example2"};
  await dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 user inserted");
  });


  dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
})
```

The output I am expecting:

```
$ npm start
    1 user inserted
    Collection deleted
    1 user inserted
    1 user inserted
    [{ _id: 1234,
      email: 'example@example.net',
      name: 'example' },
    { _id: 5678,
      email: 'example2@example.net',
      name: 'example2' }]
```

But the output I get is:

```
$ npm start
    1 user inserted
    1 user inserted
    Collection deleted
    []
    1 user inserted
```

Comment: You can `await` only on Promise object. Remove all your callback functions within `async` context. AFIAK if you don't pass callback function mongoose will return Promise.

Comment: Thank you! That resolves my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `await` only on `Promise` object. Remove all your callback functions within `async` context.

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true}, async function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  const dbo = db.db("mydb");

  var myobj = { email: "example@example.net", name: "example"};
  await dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj);
  console.log("1 user inserted");

  const delOK = await dbo.dropCollection("users");

  if (delOK) console.log("Collection deleted");

  var myobj = { email: "example@example.net", name: "example"};

  await dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj);

  console.log("1 user inserted");

  var myobj = { email: "example2@example.net", name: "example2"};
  await dbo.collection("users").insertOne(myobj);

  console.log("1 user inserted");

  const result = await dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray();

  console.log(result);
  db.close();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoClient uses callbacks rather than Promises so your awaits are currently not doing anything. You can solve this by wrapping the Mongo calls in a Promise and manually resolving them in the callback e.g.

```
const createUser = async userObj => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dbo.collection('users').insertOne(userObj, function(err, res) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve('1 user inserted');
    });
  });
};

// ...

await createUser();
```

Comment: AFIAK, mongoose do to it automatically you don't need to wrap callback with a promise

Comment: Sorry, `mongoose` => `mongodb` client